# How to verify the particular value of the DB node of firebase database

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a JSON structure as

```
    {
    "engagedUsers": {
        "qwe": {
          "agent_availability": true,
          "conv_id": "parthengineer_qwe",
          "emailId": "qwe@gmail.com",
          "login_time": 1512644440,
          "name": "qwe",
          "uid": "adasfklsfjdskldgsgjgjkl"
        },
        "tt": {
          "agent_availability": true,
          "conv_id": "genesis_tt",
          "emailId": "tt@gmail.com",
          "login_time": 1512644440,
          "name": "tt",
          "uid": "adasfklsfjdskldgsgjgjkl"
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to verify if the conv_id child is equal to **parthengineer_qwe**. I tried the below code but cannot got through it:

```
this.engagedRef = firebase.database().ref('engagedUsers');
this.engagedRef.orderByValue().once('value', function (snapshot) {

    snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
      // console.log("snapShot:" + data.child('conv_id').val());
      if ((data.child('conv_id').val() == 'parthengineerqwe') && (existEngageduser !== 1)) {
        existEngageduser = 1
        // console.log("under haschild:" + existEngageduser);
      }
      if (existEngageduser == 1) {
        isEngaged = true
        // sessionStorage.isEngaged = isEngaged;
      }
      // console.log("isEngaged:" + isEngaged);
    })
    return isEngaged;

  });
```

Please suggest a better way to achieve this as I know I am not going right way, I expect isEngaged  variable as true

Comment: Are you going to check if the value is correct for other nodes in `engagedUsers` as well?

Comment: yes, I want a true return if I get the value matched

Comment: why is your code not working?

Comment: Its returning me undefined

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what you want but why not have an external function to do it?

```
snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
    if (isEngaged(data.val())) {
      console.log(data.key, ' is engaged');
    }
}

function isEngaged(userData) {
    return (userData.conv_id === 'parthengineer_qwe') || false;
}
```